# Getting Boolean column for value in another column panda dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame and would like to create a boolean column called elevator if "Elevator" is in the amenities column.

[image]

This code generates a TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable:

```
df['elevator'] = df['amenities'].apply(lambda x: True if 'Elevator' in x else False)
```

This code generates all falses,

```
df['elevator'] = 'Elevator' in df['amenities']
```

Any idea on how I can best get the true/false if the address contains an Elevator?

Thank you.

The data frame can be created using this code:

```
pd.DataFrame({'address': {0: '201 East 12th St',
  1: 'East 17 st',
  2: '507 W 134th St Apt 54',
  3: 'Blue Slip'},
 'amenities': {0: 'Elevator',
  1: 'Elevator',
  2: 'Laundry in Unit ; Hardwood Floors',
  3: 'Doorman ; Elevator ; Laundry in Unit ; Hardwood Floors'}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `na=False` for convert `NaN`s or numeric to `False`:

Also thanks @jpp for idea for improve performance - using `regex=False`.

```
df['elevator'] = df['amenities'].str.contains('Elevator', na=False, regex=False)
print (df)
                 address                                          amenities  \
0       201 East 12th St                                           Elevator   
1             East 17 st                                           Elevator   
2  507 W 134th St Apt 54                  Laundry in Unit ; Hardwood Floors   
3              Blue Slip  Doorman ; Elevator ; Laundry in Unit ; Hardwoo...   

   elevator  
0      True  
1      True  
2     False  
3      True
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you jezrael. I cannot accept the answer for a few more minutes but will soon.